# Error in auto.arima() function

Tags: r, shiny, time-series

I'm working with time series for my thesis and I would like to know what are all the possible reasons of the error "**no suitable ARIMA models found**".
I thought that this error appears when the time series that you're trying to fit into an Arima model with the auto.arima() function is not stationary.
In my case, I have a stationary time series (I checked with ADF test, KPSS test and also looking the acf plot) and when I try to fit it with an Arima model, there is that error.
I put some regressors into the auto.arima() function because I needed, maybe also the time series of the regressors have to be stationary?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of the forecast package? 

Most likely, your regressors are collinear.

Comment: It should be the last version 7.3....I have many time series and the regressors are always the same, but only for some time series I have this error. What's the meaning of that?

Comment: You'll need to post a reproducible example to get any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that you have a problem with numerical overflow. Some of the values in the regressors are too large. Solution might be to take the log or square root of some of those variables.